# How to Mock a JDBC datasource Object causing illegal Argument exception saying Property 'data source' is required?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, datasource, spring-jdbc

my dao class contains a statement like below

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasourceResolver.selectDataSource(region));

which i m having difficulty to mock the statement

I have created mock objects for datasourceResolver and datasource in my test class and called like below in my test method but its throwing illegal Argument exception saying Property 'datasource' is required'
Mockito.when(datasourceResolver.selectDataSource(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(dataSource);

please advise how can we mock this datasource object?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of your exception, the relevant unit test and code under test. Also while mocking the jdbc datasource can be done, I would not recommend it, as you usually have to cover this by writing integration tests anyway.

Comment: i tried something like this public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
  
  dataSource.setLoginTimeout(100);
  
     return Mockito.mock(DataSource.class);
 } but its not working

Comment: Share the java code for the DAO and the Test classes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you inject mock?

Put breakpoint to `JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasourceResolver.selectDataSource(region));` line end check instance of your datasourceResolver.

Comment: yes i have injected my Dao class for which i have to write my junit. The line mentioned abpve failing with illegal arument  exception saying proeprty data source is required